# Intel iMac intermittent slows down using Photoshop (and not maxing out mem / CPU)

Tags: imac

Some days my iMac (i5 2.7GHz, 20GB mem) runs Photoshop fine. Other days it is almost unusable - the screen takes so long to re-draw that it's imposible to draw with my pen tablet.

I've checked everything I can think of:

- Watching CPU and memory graphs whilst using Photoshop. There doesn't seem to be a difference between days when it's working well and days when it's not.
- Other processes using resources. I've quit everything that I can. No difference.
- Spotlight indexing - it's not.
- SSD Smart Status - "unavailable" so I guess it could be a failing drive
- Memory integrity - I've tested with Memtest86, no errors
- Free disk space - around 50GB free
- Experimenting with different cache settings inside Photoshop - no difference
- Malware checks - ran Malwarebytes (then turned it off so it's not slowing stuff down)

Any ideas why it is sometimes slow and other times fine?

Comment: How big is your document? How many layers? What type of 'hard drive', spinny rust or SSD? 50GB might not be a lot of room if it's a small drive. Photoshop likes a lot of scratch space, which at only 50GB could start to starve your drive. [It's best on a separate SSD, if you can arrange that].

Comment: Late thought - Your SSD not showing SMART status is usually an indication that's it's connected over USB. If that's USB 2, then that's going to be very slow, possibly slower than the internal HD. The 'fix' for most of those old, slow iMacs is a big *internal* SSD.